# Populate ex command line

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to write a simple mapping that will pre-populate the vim ex command line but leave the user there to execute the command on their own.

The use-case is for the user to type `<leader>/foo` which would then open the command line with `:e **/foo` and the user could either further refine, press ctrl-d to see possible matches, etc

Comment: For those who come to this question searching for how to preserve a trailing whitespace in the mapping, the answer is [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7596/how-does-one-include-a-trailing-space-in-a-mapping).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That kind of mapping is very, very common:

```
nnoremap <leader>/ :edit **/*
```

[image: :edit]

Might I suggest the following slightly smarter alternative?

```
set path=.,**
nnoremap <leader>/ :find *
```

The `'path'` option tells Vim to look for files matching the argument given to `:find` in the directory of the file associated with the current buffer and any subdirectory of the working directory.

Reference:

```
:help :find
:help 'path'
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Why would :find be superior to :edit in this case? Is it because you can pre-filter out matches with "path" while :edit will just search for everything?

Comment: Yes. With `:edit **/foo`, your are somewhat restricted to files located below the working directory. With `:find`, you are restricted to the directories specified in `'path'`, which may or may not be under the working directory.

Comment: A quick question about this, why is a `*` necessary at the end of the find command?  I tried using that, and when I hit tab after typing a few characters in, it shows the results, then removes the star.

Comment: @EvergreenTree, `:find bar` only finds files whose name starts with `bar` but `:find *bar` also finds files containing `bar` anywhere in their name. Note that this rule also applies to `:edit` and all related commands.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to check `:h :map-<expr>`. While admittedly in this case it would be overkill, it enables mappings of the following type:

```
function! PopulateFooMap(c)
  let dict = { "r":"bar", "z":"baz" }
  return ":e **/" . get(dict, a:c, a:c)
endfunction

" very powerful
nnoremap <expr> <leader>/ PopulateFooMap(nr2char(getchar()))

" but this would still take precedence
nnoremap <leader>/f :e **/foo
```