# How can I :map a key to something containing spaces?

Tags: key-bindings, map-operator

I want to `:map <C-t> :some-ex-command` with a space at the end so I can continue typing the command and execute it with enter. I cannot find the syntax for how to do this. I tried

```
:map <C-t> :some-ex-command " "
```

which of course inserts literal `"` characters.

How can this be done?

Comment: Something like [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7596/1841)? Or you could also use `execute()` and I'm sure we also have a duplicate for that too :)